# can I redirect a route if the post was triggered by a specific control?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an app that is slowly being upgraded to MVC (MVC.net?) from ASP.net. As a consequence, I'm stuck with some awkward things like only being able to have one Form element per page because of the master page (refactoring that out would be a lot of work). Another is my little "Login/Logout" button in the corner (also on the master page). It's a lovely little holdover from the ASP.net days when everything did POST it seemed.

I've worked around this by having a method in each controller that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult CheckForLogoutButton()
{
    var coll = this.Request.Form;
    if ((coll.Cast<string>().Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        key, coll[key])).Any(x => x.Value.Contains("LoginStatus1"))))
    {                
        return RedirectToAction("LogOut", "Account", new { logout = true });
    }
    else return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Then any action that is a post has to call this method and redirect if it gets a RedirectToRouteResult. It certainly works and doesn't violate the PRG pattern. Well, we could argue that a hyperlink shouldn't be doing a POST.

**But I wonder if there's a better way.** Would it make more sense to tinker with the MVC pipeline and just check to see if this particular control ('LoginStatus1') initiated the POST, regardless of where it's headed and then redirect to the proper action? Keep in mind I have no idea if that's easy to do. The alternative is to have this bit of code in a base controller class and then *remember to check in every POST handler*. Seems like a recipe for broken code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way of doing your own fix is to make your action method a global action filter, that way you won't need to add it every time you create a controller. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx